# String Predicates to validate if a String contains numeric Value in java

Tags: java, validation, predicate

Is the any Predicate Validation in java that checks whether String contains Numbers?

I want to allow special characters but no numbers or spaces. There are Predicates that checks for alphabets but they do they do not allow Special Characters, I need something that only allows alphabets and Special characters and return false if String contains spaces or numericals.

Comment: What's your definition of special characters?

Comment: Underscores to be precise, but I want to avoid using Regex !!

Comment: Why would you want to avoid regex?

Comment: "I want to avoid using Regex" Why, when this is basically what regexes are for?

Comment: You can loop over the chars and check if `(c >= 'a' && c <= 'z') || (c >= 'A' && c <= 'Z') || z == '_'` but I don't see why you'd want to.

Comment: Well long story to avoid regex but for now I need to know if there exist a Predicate that solves the above conditions

Comment: Thre predicate you will create will contain regex. this is what regex is invented for.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I will use an regex to show my understanding of the question. You want a `Predicate<String>` that returns true for any string matching

```
[a-zA-Z_]*
```

One way to do this regexlessly is to use a for loop and check each character:

```
Predicate<String> predicate = x -> {
    for (int i = 0 ; i < x.length() ; i++) {
        if (!Character.isLetter(x.charAt(i)) && !x.charAt(i) == '_') {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
};
```

Here is a method that does the same thing:

```
public static boolean test(String x) {
    for (int i = 0 ; i < x.length() ; i++) {
        if (!Character.isLetter(x.charAt(i)) && !x.charAt(i) == '_') {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: You can use it like so: `predicate.test("Your string")`. You said you wanted a predicate so i gave you one. Do you want a method or something? @Alex

Comment: Yes I do, I'm kind of new to Predicates so a detailed answer would be appreciated !

Answer (score 3):

It may be done in a more elegant way:

```
Predicate<String> p = (s -> s.matches("[a-zA-Z\\_]*"));
```

Returning true for any string matching [a-zA-Z_]*.

Answer (score 0):

Since your predicate shall return false if the string contains at least one digit or space character and else true, you can do the following:

```
Predicate<String> p = s -> !s.matches(".*[ \\d].*");
```

The advantage of this method is that every UTF-8 letter and every special character is valid in p.  For some reason the other ansers allow only for ASCII letters ([a-zA-Z] and allow only underscores.  I guess the question has been rewritten in the meanwhile.